# Image processing algorithm

Tags: python, opencv

Can you give me a idea about image processing segmentation algorithm invariant to light that can be implemented in Opencv in Jupyter Notebook?Please!

Comment: Algorithm for what? Segmentation clustering or object recognition?!

Comment: For segmentation.

Comment: Have you tried googling? There are millions of results for "python opencv image segmentation". Some of them find a specific object in an image and segment it out, other will try full image segmentation. If you want the latter, I would recommend looking at modelling approaches outside of OpenCV for the best results.

Comment: Segnet is an easy one which is already implemented.

Comment: Try kmeans https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html